# How to unlock admin account

Tags: debian, passwd, accounts

By mistake I locked my admin account on Debian with passwd -l.
I'm trying with live CD to unlock my account with no sucess. I've tried editing passwd file by removing x, but that didn't work.

```
/etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

any ideas?

Comment: The password is store in the shadow files

Comment: I know, i mounted ssd drive but all i see is .efi file!

Comment: Edited from recovery mode. Solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an account with `sudo` permission, you can run:

```
sudo passwd root
```

to unlock root password.

If you don't have `sudo` permission, you should boot into single user mode (by editing boot option if you use `grub`) or using a `live cd`, then editing `/etc/shadow` file (not `/etc/passwd`) to remove pair of exclamation mark `!!` or `!` before hash password, example:

```
root:!!<hash password here>:9797:0:::::
```

After that, reboot and now you can log in with root again.

Comment: I know, i mounted ssd drive but all i see is .efi file!

Answer (score 1):

The password is not store in `/etc/passwd` the x is a dummy entry `/etc/shadow` contains the password.

Read `man shadow` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't even need to boot with a LiveCD, simply boot your system with either the string `1` or the word `single` at the end of your `linux ...` stanza when GRUB2 initially is displayed.

#### Example

When booting the system if you access the boot menu options for the kernel from the GRUB2 menu, you can append the appropriate string at the end to gain single user mode access to your system.

> linux /vmlinuz-3.13.5-101.fc19.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root ro rd.md=0 rd.dm=0 vconsole.keymap=us rd.lvm.lv=fedora_greeneggs/swap
>     rd.lvm.lv=fedora_greeneggs/root rd.luks=0 vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8 single

**NOTE:** You typically hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key and then arrow down to the `linux ...` line adding the string "single" to the end. Then hit the <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot it.

Once booted you should be able to access your `/etc/shadow` file and remove the existing password from root's entry, making it blank. If you then reboot the system you should be able to get in with a blank password and use `passwd` to reset it.